# draw circle around an image, bigger than the image in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, uiimage

I am trying to draw a circle on `UIImageView` :

```
+(UIImageView *) getRoundedImageView:(float)borderWidth :(UIImageView *)imageView :(UIColor *)borderColor{
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.width/2.0;
    imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true;
    imageView.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth;
    imageView.layer.borderColor = [borderColor CGColor];
    return imageView;
}
```

It gives me this:[image]
I want to draw a circle with some space around the check mark.If I increase the dimensions of the `UIImageView`, The image size also increases.

I have tried applying

```
   UIImage* statusImage = [Utility getStatusImage:(status)];
   UIImageView* statusImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width-40,17+5,25,25)];
   statusImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

But this doesnt work, I still get an image with a bigger check mark and no space between image and the circle.

Comment: the contentMode you have set will change the size of the image to fit the imageView. I would suggest using a different export of the image asset that has more padding between the check mark and the edges of the image

Answer (score 1):

Put your `UIImageView` as subview in another `UIView` and scale up this `UIView`.

Or change your `UIImageView` `contentMode` property.

```
statusImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
```

Comment: I thought about it but It sounded a little hackish to me.  Would this be the right way to do it ?

Comment: @user1324887 There's `contentMode` - `Center` which won't scale up or down your image and set it to center of `UIImageView`, but make sure, that your asset is exactly the size you want.

Comment: UIViewContentModeCenter didn't work. I will try putting `UIImageView ` inside a `UIView` or getting another asset as @@MarkEdwardMurray suggested.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit your Image** Make a circle around your Image and add it to UIImageView : )